# Why am I getting this error? Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

I accidentally uploaded an image to "My resources" which had the same name as another image in my resources and since then VB is showing up over 100 errors, but I don't know what I can do to resolve it and restore the program?

It's a very large program that I have been working on for months and really don't want to have to restart!

I have looked online and even found posts on here, but it doesn't work.

I have deleted the repeating image name, in my resources, but still doesn't resolve it. Whenever I go onto "My Project" > "Resources" it comes up with "There is already another resource with the name "Back_button."

But I removed it?

This is the error that comes up for all of the images/items that were in my resources:

```
"Beach_Text" is not a member of 'Top_of_the_Class.My.Resources'.
```

I also have a warning:

```
The designer cannot process the code at line 74: Me.btnInstructions.Image = Global.Top_of_the_Class.My.Resources.Resources.Instructions_button

The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.
```

I hope this makes sense and I know others have asked similar questions, but I have tried them methods. I just want my program back :(

Many thanks.

Comment: It's not a solution, but if you embarked on a large scale, multi-month long project and didn't use some sort of version control, you were just asking for a problem.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project?... SELECT Build --> CLEAN XXX. I would also try closing down VS2010 and restarting it, especially after a clean.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Shift+F` and search for "Back_button" or whaterver and it will search in the resource files (.resx extesion) for the definition. With a few global find and replaces you should be fine.

Comment: It's just a college project, but I don't understand how all of these errors have appeared :(

Comment: I blame `VB.NET` for hiding everything under many layers of generated code in hidden files.

Comment: Did you remove the call to `InitializeComponent` in the constructors of any of your forms? You may have to fire up a text editor and take a look at the `.resx` files for your forms or `Resources.resx` and `Resources.Designer.vb` under the `My Project` folder to look for the duplicate it is talking about. but make you make a backup first if you're not using version control!!!

Comment: If you don't have a backup to go to try right clicking on the project folder in Windows Explorer and see if Restore Previous Versions is an option.

Comment: the designer generated code may still contain references to the now deleted resource.  Click 'show all files" in solution explorer, then open the XXX.designer.vb file (XXX=filename of the form which is the source of error msgs), then **carefully** remove references to whatever was lost.  You might also be able to extract the now lost resource from the last good build ... but that is a different question

Comment: Thank you everyone! I have, doing what Plutonix said, managed to remove all of the errors a part from 1 now. Just trying to get rid of this error: Invalid Resx file. Could not find 'E:\Top of the Class\Top of the Class\Resources\Back_button.png.' Line 933, position 5. It occurred after I removed the item from the resources and isn't there anymore, so where is line 933 if there isn't one? Is it somewhere else in the document? :/ Honestly, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I didn't wanted to restart my whole program and also I didn't used version control. If I went to the resources tab there was an error saying: There is already another resource with the name "Donkey_Kong". I pressed on **ctrl-shift-F** and searched for Donkey_kong and deleted every posible resource and code with the name Donkey_Kong in it. After I did that the error dissapeared and it was solved.
*I had a picture with the name Donkey_Kong and a sound file with the name Donkey_Kong. Changed the names and continued :)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ("There is already another resource with the name "Salary")

1. Removed two lines of codes with the same resource name and
2. I went to Project--->Properties of my project--> went to resources tab and DELETED all files/images... with the same name "Salary" and the problem was fixed (All my codes were still there)